# I have 4 days, should I learn QT or Java swing?

Tags: swing, qt, user-interface

I need to build a File browser demo by this Friday, which is used to browse mp3 files and display their track info such as artist and title.

I have no experience in both of them, and same amount of experience in Java and C++.

The core functionality is finished in c++. Just need to have a gui to browse , select file and call functions based on selected files.

Which one should I chose? Tutorials are much appreciated. (I know there are lots of them online but I'm not sure which one can let me finish my job in 3-4 days)

Comment: Dude/Dudette, you're going to get down-voted to oblivion for this. Nonetheless, the choice is still up to you. However, this link may help you determine which one is better suited for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422956/java-swing-or-java-qt

Also, it would be easier to simply try one or two examples in each, see which one appeals to you and go from there since you'll naturally have an affinity to either.

Comment: I think you're better off with Swing, IMO - since you don't need any other external libraries, there are a lot of tutorials and examples online for you to try. All you need is a JDK, a code editor and you're set.

Comment: i think qt aldy has that kind of tutorial.

Comment: Open ended questions are not constructive in the Stack Overflow question/answer format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is my vote, too.

The examples and info in the links below should get you well on your way to your solution.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-qmusicplayer.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html

PS, After installing Qt and Qt Creator, it has fantastic documentation and great examples and tutorials easily accessed from the IDE, on the Welcome tab.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the short time span, I suggest using Qt. Go to the website http://qt.digia.com/Product/Developer-Tools/ and download Qt Creator IDE. It has a nice GUI builder that allows you to drag and drop components in a WYSIWYG editor. Make sure to read about signals and slots in Qt. There are a lot of good tutorials at the website and Qt is well documented. If you work hard at it, you could get your GUI set up and connected to your core code in time. Good luck.

BTW: Qt uses C++ and has additional library of Qt specific objects.